# Instantiating dependencies in Laravel 5, the good way

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Laravel 5 offers automatic dependency resolving if I type-hint the needed class/interface. But how should they be instantiated? Example:

```
public function __construct(Dependency $dependency) {
    $this->dependency = $dependency;
}
```

And then, in another method, I'd like to create two instances, like this:

```
$one = new Dependency(1);
$two = new Dependency(2);
```

What is the most flexible and test-friendly way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Excuse my poor joke, but it depends.

It looks like you have misunderstood the dependency resolving a little bit.
In your example the property 'dependency' allready contains an instantiated object. If you need two different instances within another method you may instantiate them there, inject a container or use a factory. It depends on your needs.

**a very short introduction to laravel dependency resolving**

The automatic dependency resolving in laravel is provided by the [service container](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container) and it is used to deliver an (allready) instantiated object. The resolved object must be binded to service container. The best way to do this is via [service providers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers). Within the register method of a service provider you are able to do your bindings

```
$this->app->bind('Dependency', function ($app) {
    return new Dependency();
});
```

In this example the container will return a new instance every time it is called.

If you need the same instance every time you may bind a singleton

```
$this->app->singleton('Dependency', function ($app) {
    return new Dependency();
});
```

Comment: OK I know that, but how do you pass params to the constructor? I haven't instantiated `new Dependency`, but `new Dependency(1)` and `new Dependency(2)`.

Comment: Then I need  a more concrete example to understand your question. You are able to pass a parameter before  instantiation within the binding (eg. `return new Dependency(1);`. You may also access the IOC (through `$app`) or the settings (eg. `return new Dependency(config('something'))` ) within the service provider.

Comment: Let's say I need a model class that is instantiated with some data and this data is available in the class that is using that dependency. Good example is controller and model, where I need to get - let's say - a user. Eloquent models have `newInstance()` method, but it's not a standard for other classes.

Comment: For such a scenario I would pass a user repository to the constructor of the controller and use this within the methods. This is a common and testable way to achieve this [link](http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern).